# Blender 2.8 reference image disappeared

Tags: modeling, image

I am currently working on a 3D model and I was using a reference image to get the proportions right. Sine 2.8 doesnt have the background image feature I was using an empty object as image. After fixing up some non-manifold edges I just noticed my reference is not visible anymore even though it is still listed in the outliner.

Does someone know why that is and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image empties are as overlays and you disabled them to display. Enable them back and your image will be displayed again:

[image: demo pic]

Answer (score 4):

Are you in local view? In that case <kbd>/</kbd> (or *View > Local View > Toggle Local View*) should bring everything back

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried toggling local view for all of the objects and the collections but the reference image does not come back.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't guess right what your problem was :)

Answer (score 2):

Since I have found this topic while having that same issue with Blender 2.9, I want to add that I had to solve it by re-enabling Extras. Wich might be what L0Lock meant for 2.8. After re-enabling Extras, my reference images were present again.

[image: Image showing where extra button display is]

Comment: Tried that solution, not working... Any workaround? Using 2.9 too...

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.0 if you're Overlays are on and you're able to see it in render mode but not in wireframe mode then the issue may something in the Object Properties tab for the image.

Make sure Depth is set to Default. Also, make sure the Opacity is something other than zero. If you want to see it from a non-orthographic perspective there is a check box for that in this tab as well.

[image]